# Order not working correctly in MDX

Tags: mdx

I'm new to MDX and I cannot get the ordering correct. I looked at references online and I think i sorted the query correctly, but the result of the query doesn't agree with me. Can anyone shed some light into what I'm not doing.

I have included a hypothetical example that is close to my problem.

[image]

The result of the query comes out without being sorted.

[image]

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want your result to be sorted by? SalesPersonID?

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument to the Order()-function on your Rows-axis, must be the value or string to sort by. If you want to sort by the names of the SalespersonID-members, do something like this:

```
Order([Sales].[SalespersonID], [Sales].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_NAME) on Rows
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try that : "Query (3, 33) The CURRENTMEMBER function expects a hierarchy expression for the 1 argument. A member expression was used "    I did put BASC after the 2nd argument.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Try removing the [SalespersonID] from the 2nd argument of the Order-function - that should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Dan,  I tried Order([Sales].[SalespersonID], [Sales].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_NAME) on Rows  and Order([Sales].[SalespersonID], [Sales].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_NAME, BASC) on Rows, but the results don't seem to be sorted.  Martin gets sorted before Howard, and Howard before Fisher as an example.

Comment: Could you try writing `CURRENTMEMBER.Name` instead of `CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_NAME` ?

Comment: I've tried that as well, it didn't make a difference